# Where to put ${library.pipeline-utils.version} when using Git SCM to setup Global Pipeline Library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to setup a global pipeline library that will be explicitly loaded using `@Library()` per [these instruction](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin#defining-external-libraries).  I have this working fine with respect to loading the default library version from master branch.

What I am unable to do is figure out how to configure things so that it can load different branches upon request using the `Library('lib-name@branch-name')` syntax.

The instructions say:

> "When using Legacy SCM, you will need to include ${library.pipeline-utils.version} in the SCM configuration somewhere."

I have tried using `${library.pipeline-utils.version}` as the value for the `Branch Specifier` which is the only logical place I can think to put it. But that just break things.  Attempts to load the library fail with:

```
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@stash:7999/jen/pipeline-utils.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@stash:7999/jen/pipeline-utils.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/${library.pipeline-utils.version}^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/${library.pipeline-utils.version}^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/${library.pipeline-utils.version}^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

This makes me think I put the variable in the right place but Jenkins is not interpolating it. (Bug?)

This is using Jenkins 2.7.1 and Pipeline version 2.4

Comment: Good job locating this plugin, now I'm aware one exists. Used self-invented trick for a task alike before. I'll answer to your question when/if I'll be able to handle it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is finally now a 'modern scm' implementation for Git that works as we are using that.

Comment: Can you please specify what _modern scm_ you're referring to? Is this a new plugin or a new version of the existing SCM plugin? A link would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I set it, using version variable `${library.CpsGlobal.version}` and `Branches to build / Branch Specifier` :

[image]

ps. Please remove "`-`" character from library name as it's not supported by Groovy.

Comment: Thats the obvious answer and I tired that.  Plan to try again now that I have the latest pipeline version.  Will let you know how it goes.

RE: Goovy not supporting hyphens in library names, can you clarify this?  This is not a groovy thing as I understand it, but a Jenkins thing.  In groovy its nothing more than an string arg passed into the @Library attribute.

Comment: @luka5z I've tried using environment variables to define branch specifiers in the past, but those attempts failed. Jenkins would not interpolate the variable —e.g. `${BRANCH_SELECTOR}`. Do you know by any chance why this works for `${library.CpsGlobal.version}` and not when using an environment variable? Or if it _should_ work, then what version of the SCM and/or Pipeline plugins does that require?

Comment: That `ps. Please remove "-" character from library name as it's not supported by Groovy.` saved me! I was going crazy why my branch isn't checked out and why that variable wasn't replaced! Any link to official docs that say this? Because I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Work for me:

- Library name: testlib
- Default version: branchname
- Branches to build: ${library.testlib.version}